# Custom Element in Angular 17

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements, angular17

since I updated Angular to version 17 I can't create web components..
I used to do it in app.module, where are they created now?
I tried in app.component as the guide says but it doesn't seem to work..
Can someone help me please??

I tried in app.component as the guide says but it doesn't seem to work..

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <input #input value="Message" />
    <button type="button" (click)="popup.showAsElement(input.value)">Show as element</button>
  `,
  providers: [PopupService],
  imports: [PopupComponent],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    public popup: PopupService,
  ) {
    // Convert `PopupComponent` to a custom element.
    const PopupElement = createCustomElement(PopupComponent, {injector});
    // Register the custom element with the browser.
    customElements.define('popup-element', PopupElement);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the way to create a custom Element

In your main.ts

```
//remove
// bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {providers:[...]})
//   .catch((err) => console.error(err));

//and replace with:
(async () => {
  const app = createApplication({providers:[...]});
  const PopupElement = createCustomElement(AppComponent, {
    injector: (await app).injector
  });

  customElements.define('popup-element', PopupElement);

})();
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-d2mqpk?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html&title=Angular%20Starter) (see that, you need refresh the "visor" if you make any change)

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, it was very helpful for me.
I would like to ask you something else:
after making the changes you suggested, the customElement is created.
For clarity let's call the project where I create the element project 1 and the other project 2.
If I wanted to export the element to project 2, how can I do it?
I tried copying the js of the dist in project 2 and putting them as src.
Then in the body I recalled the element with the <popup-element> tag but it doesn't understand that it is a custom element.
ps: I have already added the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA

Comment: @nixxx, I think remember that you should add the `<script src=...></script>` **at the end of your page -inside the body-**, but now I'm not pretty sure.

Comment: @Eliseo where did you get that puiece of code?

"See the way to create a custom Element in your main.ts"

thanks

Comment: @StefanoFavero, see your `angular.json` file. In projects-->ClientApp-->Architect-->build-->options-->main you have the file.ts that have been executed. Generally is called main.ts. and the main.ts can be in the way `bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,...` if you're working with standalone components or `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)...` if you're using modules. This is the code you need replace to create elements

Comment: @Eliseo
it gives me the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at main.js:25942:1)` in prod build, however works well with `ng serve`